How to find the interior of $A = (-\infty, -4] \cup (2, 5)$?
I'm working on a problem involving the topological interior of a set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. The set is defined as:
$$A = (-\infty, -4] \cup (2, 5).$$
I understand that the interior of a set is the largest open set contained within it, but I’m not entirely sure how to handle the closed boundary at $-4$ and how the union of these intervals affects the result. Here's what I've done so far:
The interval $(-\infty, -4]$ is not open because it includes the point $-4$, but $(-\infty, -4)$ is open. So, the interior of this part should be $(-\infty, -4)$.
The interval $(2, 5)$ is already open, so its interior should just be $(2, 5)$.
Is my reasoning correct that the interior of $A$ is:
$$\operatorname{int}(A) = (-\infty, -4) \cup (2, 5) \,\, ?$$
Also, more generally, how does the interior of a union of intervals behave? Does $\operatorname{int}(A \cup B) = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{int}(B)$ always hold, or are there cases where this fails?
Any clarification on both points would be appreciated!

$Int ((0,1)\cup[1,2))=(0,2)\neq Int ((0,1) \cup Int ([1,2))$

@geetha290krm oh yeah, that's a good one. thanks!

In this case $int(A)$ is exactly what you found but in general you only have $int(A) \cup int(B) \subset int(A \cup B)$.

A union of open sets is always open, But for non-open sets, the best you can say is that the union of the interiors is a subset of the interior of the union. Some boundary points of individual sets may find themselves completely surrounded in the union, and thus part of its interior, even though they were not in the interior of any of the original sets. This is true for intervals, or any other sets.
